# C++: location of definition/declaration of non-member function

Tags: c++

I have a class Myclass:

in Myclass.h file:

```
class{
private:
    int sd;
    int sd2;

public:
    void func(int sd, short op, void *ptr);

    void start();
};
```

in Myclass.cpp file:

```
void Myclass::start(){
     struct arg_t *arg = (struct arg_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct arg_t));
     ....
     event_set(ev, sd, EV_READ, call_func, arg ); //this is a library API, which trigger the callback of call_func(sd, op, arg);
}

void Myclass::func(int sd, short op, void *ptr)){
...
if(some_conditions){
     struct arg_t *arg = (struct arg_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct arg_t))
     .... 
     event_set(ev, sd2, EV_READ, call_func, arg );
     .....

}
...
}
```

in main.cpp

```
int main(){
   Myclass obj;
   ....
   obj.start();
   ....
}
```

in start(), the event_set need a function of `void(*func)()` type as argument,but func() is of  `void Myclass::(*func)()` type, so I define a new function something like below (the codes are not correct, but just show what I expect):

```
void call_func(int sd, short op, void *ptr){
    Myclass::func(int sd, short op, void *ptr);
}
```

however, I'm at a loss where to delcare and define `call_func()` so that the `Myclass::start()` can use `call_func` as argument and `call_func()` can call `Myclass::func()`

Comment: Just make `Myclass::func` `static` and call it in `event_set(Myclass::func)`

Comment: Anywhere above the definition of `Myclass::start` should do.

Comment: @JameyD  no, that static function can't access the non-static member variables and functions, which is not desired.

Comment: @molbdnilo  where to declare it and where to define it? in the .cpp file or .h file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem. Since pointers to class members are not regular pointers, one can not use class member functions in naive callbacks, which expect a simple function pointer.

A solution is to make a callback function `static`, often `private`, and call the corresponding class function using the callback argument. In your case, it would look like following:

```
class C {
private:
    int sd;
    static void call_func(int sd, short op, void* ptr) {
        C* obj = static_cast<C*>(ptr);
        obj->func(sd, op);
    }


public:
    void func(int sd, short op);

    void start()  {
        event_set(ev, sd, EV_READ, &call_func, this);
    }
};
```

**EDIT**

Fixed messed up `start()` and `func()`.

Comment: that static function can't access the non-static member variables and functions, which is not desired.

Comment: That's why you give it "this" as the "ptr" argument

Comment: @SergeyA now you aren't passing a third parameter to `func`. +1 anyway, lily seems to be looking for this.

Comment: @user2079303, this is how it was defined in the original example.

Comment: @SergeyA the syntax for calling `func` is wrong in the original example, but it does (try to) pass the third parameter to it. Your code doesn't.

Comment: thank you very much. but the last argument of event_set() is still needed to be used for a pointer to an additional structure, so it can't be `this`

Comment: @lily, just put this additional structure as a member of your class. Than `func()` will be able to access it.

Comment: @SergeyA  there are multiple(non-determinstic number of) structures, not only one

Comment: @lily, and why all of them can not be members of your class? What is indtended usage of this void* ptr in callback?

Comment: @SergeyA because I don't know how many of them are there. There may be a lot of malloc(), depending on the running.

Comment: @lily, that you need some indication in the class which will tell you which structure you need to use. If you can't do this, than you can't make those functions members of the class using conventional techniques, as you only have one callback argument. You can still use unconvential techniques - for instance, try to do something like ATL thunks - but I certainly would not recommend this.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm at a loss where to delcare and define `call_func()` so that the `Myclass::start()` can use `call_func` as argument and `call_func()` can call `Myclass::func()`

You can put this all in your Myclass.cpp file, above the definition of Myclass::start().`

```
#include <Myclass.h>

void call_func(int sd, short op, void *ptr){
    Myclass::func(int sd, short op, void *ptr);
}

void Myclass::start(){
     event_set(ev, sd, EV_READ, call_func, NULL ); //this is a library API, which trigger the callback of call_func(sd, op, NULL);
}

void Myclass::func(int sd, short op, void *ptr)){
...
...
}
```

One other thing, with callback functions, the `void* ptr` is how you can pass a pointer to some data that the callback function will use. If you don't need anything like that then you don't need to be calling a non-static member function as the callback and you could simplify things. But to call non-static member function the way you're describing, you need an object to call it on, and that's what you would pass as the `void *ptr`:

```
// Myclass.h
class Myclass {
private:
    int sd;

public:
    void func(int sd, short op); // no void*
    void start();
};


// Myclass.cpp
#include <Myclass.h>

void call_func(int sd, short op, void *ptr){
    assert(ptr != NULL);
    static_cast<Myclass *>(ptr)->func(int sd, short op); // cast data to 'this' pointer
}

void Myclass::start(){
     event_set(ev, sd, EV_READ, call_func, this ); // pass the 'this' pointer as data
}

void Myclass::func(int sd, short op)){
...
...
}
```

> the last argument of `event_set()` is still needed to be used for a pointer to an additional structure, so it can't be `this`

You need to pass `this` somehow or you can't call a member function, so if you have another structure you need to think about how to pass both.

Can the other structure or a pointer to it be a member of the object? If so, then do that and pass `this` as the `void *ptr`.

Another option is to define a `struct` just for passing the data through the callback:

```
struct callback_params {
  Myclass *c;
  other_struct *s;
};
```

But you have to create this `callback_params` struct somewhere where it will live long enough for the callback to be able to receive it, which can be tricky.

Answer (score -3):

#### WRONG ANSWER!!!!

**My old tablet didn't load the code sections of the question 
correctly and I miss important parts of the question...

Leaving here just as sake of completeness - maybe this can be util
for someone else**

**SORRY**

I don't know the complete stuff that you're doing but in this cases, 
if i don't need interface with old code I will go for `std::function` for sure.

But if is absolutely needed the pointers stuff, I generally do:

- Put a very ugly name in the function - So every one will know that this is a 'hack' and not a good thing. ex: `_func_call_wrapper_(...)`
- Put into the top of .cpp file the definition with the appropriated comments and so on. ex:

`//This is a wrapper neeeded for...
void __func_call_wrappper_(..);`

- Finally in the bottom of the .cpp file I define the function, of course, 
  with a lot of comments of why this is needed.

Refs:
[ccpreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)